# Programatically access validation applied to DbContext via Fluent API

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

Consider the following entities:

```
public partial class User
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual long DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department{ get; set; }
}

public partial class Department
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating (DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>();
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasKey<long>(p => p.Id);
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(p => p.Email).IsRequired().IsMaxLength();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Department>();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().HasKey<long>(p => p.Id);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Department>().Property(p => p.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(256);
}
```

I deliberately skipped out relationship mapping above as it is not relevant to the question.

I am generating DTOs and MVC models based on these hand-written entities and would like to access property configurations defined in the `OnModelCreating` method programatically.

I do remember there was a way to access the model/schema using the DbContext object but have not found a way to achieve the above in various searches. Any pointers would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**: After adding code suggested in the answer below, I'm getting a strange exception for which searching has been in vain.

```
Error   2   Running transformation: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Entry point was not found.
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.get_ObjectContext()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating4060E50565D24E6D60BA3E80DDCE2A21E9485A5F4982CD591645549489576DC7687B06DE6C675CAA51175F177B32340E9E07C1C8B0487B2BD65D022D75892D00.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is the metadata workspace:

```
var db = new YourDbContext();
var oc = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
var mw = oc.MetadataWorkspace;
```

Then you can access the model through it. For example, you can get the names of all the entities:

```
var entities = mw.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.OSpace);
foreach (var entity in entities)
  Console.WriteLine(entity.Name);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm facing a strange issue after adding this code to the T4. Have updated the question.